how to declare new math operator with opentype fonts
I see many answers using mathchoice but for OpenType fonts this should work differently.
The question is this: In opentype, say the integral, has a slot called "integral" and another one called "integral.v1". The integral is declared as extensible glyph and the vertical construction in the Math table is
integral: integral integral.v1

So integral is used inline and integral.v1 in display mode.
Now assume we need a new glyph to behave the same way. We have glyph declared as extensible, glyph.v1 for the display version and
glyph: glyph glyph.v1

in the opentype math table.
If I \DeclareMathOperator*{\myglyph}{"glyph}
then the position of the limits work properly in inline and display mode, but in display mode the glyph.v1 is not chosen. It always gives the inline version.
What is the proper to define \myglyph so the .v1 version is used in display mode?
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[olddefault]{fontsetup} 
\DeclareMathOperator*{\convolution}{\char"E036} 

\begin{document} 
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\convolution_{m=1}^{k_n}f_{nm}$. 
\[
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\convolution_{m=1}^{k_n}f_{nm}.
\]
\end{document}

You can get a font with uniE036 as in the above code from here link
Next is a solution with \mathchoice which does not answer the original question as it is based on plain TeX and not on the OpenType facilities. NewCM convolving functions:


Upvoted, but I think you can improve the question by giving a small test file, where you specify one concrete example where this situation occurs. It is then easier for others to test and help.

OK then. One "forgotten" operator is the convolution of functions denoted by a star. I want to fill in this gap for NewCM. This font link   contains uniE0036 and uniE0036.v1 properly setup from the font side. A test file can be as follows: \documentclass{article} \usepackage[olddefault]{fontsetup} \DeclareMathOperator*{\convolution}{\char"E036} \begin{document} $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\convolution_{m=1}^{k_n}f_{nm}$. $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\convolution_{m=1}^{k_n}f_{nm}.$$ \end{document}

Good! I don't know how to do such an definition properly in LaTeX, but I know how to do in ConTeXt, and whatever it is worth, I can confirm that your font seems to work. Let us hope someone who knows the LaTeX way shows up...

Thanks @mickep It is good to have confirmed that the font is OK.

I've taken the liberty of copying your sample code into the body of your query, where it was easier to format for ease of parsing. Feel free to revert.

Is convolution extensible or is it just available in the different sizes? because you probably want to look at an existing symbol of the same kind. (Note I don't know how this works for unicode maths - just thinking about the standard setup.)

yes it is declared extensible in the open type Math table and this is why it works with conTeXt as @mickep wrote above.

Thanks @Mico I also added the link to the test font.

have you looked at how unicode-math does it?

Most probably this is my problem. I do not understand how unicode-math does it.

Maybe it does it by \mathchoice and uses XeTeXglyph (and similarly for lua) to pick up glyphs by name. If this is true it is better to stick with \mathchoice

But again that can not be. Because \mathchoice does not care if the inline glyph is declared extensible or not in the opentype math table. So there must be another mechanism here.

As far as I can tell, it uses it for root symbols in luatex. that seems to be it. so, no, I don't think that's how unicode-math does it. as far as I understand what little I've read, it relies on a table listing all known Unicode math symbols which is, I think, separate from unicode-math. Is your symbol included?  if so, that's probably the place to start?

Ah, you say that they use some kind of preset based on the Unicode standard. If this is the case, and it could be true as all this (about math tables in opentype) started from Microsoft, then my only choice is to setup things with \mathchoice. Which is OK, I just wanted to make sure. No the new character is not in Unicode standard. It is an advanced Math operation on functions which has been forgotten from both the Unicode and the TeX world. This is why I place the glyphs are in Private Use Area of Unicode.

Hmm ... you shouldn't take my comment as in any way authoritative! I just looked through the documentation and that seemed to be the idea, but I didn't read it all or look at much of the code (except to grep \mathchoice). based on what unicode-math says, you might try looking at what stix does to support their fonts since they apparently use stuff from the pua. (but whether that supports the sizing distinctions, I don't know.) if you think it should be in Unicode, you should maybe tell barbara.

@Antonis no unicode math just access the character via its mathchardef just as in classic tex.

@Antonis I see no reason to use the private use area here you could use one of the existing * slots

@cfr unicode-math doesn't require the symbol to be decalred in unicode, so long as you declare it as a bigop like \sum  and the font specifies a larger character, it'll get used.

@DavidCarlisle thanks. I did say I didn't read it. I thought 'extensible' meant something different, too.


You can't access the character via \char which is for text and doesn't trigger the math processing.  Just declare it as mathclass 1 (bigop) so the same mechanism as \sum will kick in.
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont[Path=./]{NewCMMath-Regular.otf}

\Umathchardef \convolution 1 2 "E036



\begin{document}


$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\convolution_{m=1}^{k_n}f_{nm}$. 
\[
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\convolution_{m=1}^{k_n}f_{nm}.
\]
\end{document}


Yes! Great. That works fine (as well as \mathchoice :-) ) Thanks David.
